# Are there any problems dealing with files with XBAP?

Tags: wpf, asp.net-mvc, xbap

We are working on a project (web, asp .net mvc) which requires a lot of file interaction like editing word templates. We found that it is pretty easy to bring the file contents into WPF rich textbox (as RTF) and save it.

The question I want to ask is: Are there any gotchas when it comes to handling files in XBAP since we are going to invoke the wpf application as XBAP?

Comment: Are you deploying this internally? I ran into a lot of security issues with an XBAP I made a few years ago and had install a certificate on the client computers so we could do database access and some IO stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...We are deploying this internally (LAN)...I know that there would be some kind of security issues since that application is going to access files from a network share...but other than that we are worried since this is the first time we are doing this.